# How to pull in the latest changes made in Webkit

Tags: git

I have followed this instruction in setting my webkit repository locally:

http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/UsingGitWithWebKit

And then I made some changes locally.

My question is how can I sync up my repository to the master Webkit repository?
I tried 'git fetch', i don't see files are added/deleted.

And then I tried 'git pull', I do see files are added/deteted.
Like this:

```
WebKitTools/ChangeLog                              |    6 +
 WebKitTools/Scripts/webkitpy/committers.py         |    2 +-
 157 files changed, 1441 insertions(+), 1167 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 LayoutTests/fast/text/line-break-after-question-mark-expected.txt
 create mode 100644 LayoutTests/fast/text/line-break-after-question-mark.html
 create mode 100644 LayoutTests/fast/text/script-tests/line-break-after-question-mark.js
 delete mode 100644 LayoutTests/storage/domstorage/documentURI.html
 create mode 100644 LayoutTests/storage/domstorage/events/basic-body-attribute-expected.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git fetch` only fetches changes from remote repository, but not merge your local `master` branch with remote. You can always `git merge` or `git rebase` to `origin/master`, or do it with just one command: `git pull` of `git pull --rebase`.

`git pull` is preffered way if you want to get changes from remote, it does `fetch` and `merge`.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me what is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git pull --rebase'?

Comment: @n179911 `git pull` fetches changes from remote repository and then merges them to master. `git pull --rebase` makes rebase instead. If you have local changes, then merge will create merge commit with 2 parents, but rebase will get all your local changes and apply then onto o new master (as fetched from repository). See http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html for more info and examples. If you don't have local changes, then both will work same way.